# Max Memory Size for a Thread on a 32 bit process

Tags: windows, memory-management, out-of-memory, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I know there is a 4gb limit for each process when running in 32 bits .... but if a process has multiple threads... does all the memory usage of each thread add up to the total of 4gb? Or does each thread get 4gb of individual memory space to use?

Comment: That's sort of the point of threads: All threads share the same address space within a process. If you wanted separate address spaces for each thread, then put each thread in its own process. The process is the thing that has an address space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all live in the same address space. So - yes, this is a limit for all threads inside a process.